# What is causing the "error LNK2005: already defined in .obj" s errors in my code?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, lnk2005

I would like to know what is causing a double definition linker error in my code. It confuses me because there doesn't seem to be any reason for it. I don't think I'm `#include`ing any `.h` files in places that would cause this, as my file's `#include`s are linearly structured.

To be clear, I am not asking what the errors mean, I am asking what, in my code, is causing it. I have already researched on this site (and others) as to what it means, and can't find an answer relevant to what could be causing it in my code.

Btw I am using Visual Studio 2017

Here are the errors:

```
1>ObjectHandler.cpp

1>Main.cpp

1>Generating Code...

1>ObjectHandler.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl pixelsInit(void)" (?
pixelsInit@@YAXXZ) already defined in Main.obj

1>ObjectHandler.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl pixelsUpdate(void)" (?
pixelsUpdate@@YAXXZ) already defined in Main.obj

1>ObjectHandler.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl spritesInit(void)" (?
spritesInit@@YAXXZ) already defined in Main.obj

1>ObjectHandler.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl spritesUpdate(void)" (?
spritesUpdate@@YAXXZ) already defined in Main.obj

1>ObjectHandler.obj : error LNK2005: "class std::vector<struct pixel,class 
std::allocator<struct pixel> > pixels" (?pixels@@3V?$vector@Upixel@@V?
$allocator@Upixel@@@std@@@std@@A) already defined in Main.obj

1>ObjectHandler.obj : error LNK2005: "class std::map<class 
std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class 
std::allocator<char> >,struct sprite,struct std::less<class 
std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class 
std::allocator<char> > >,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<class 
std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class 
std::allocator<char> > const ,struct sprite> > > sprites" (?sprites@@3V?
$map@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?
$allocator@D@2@@std@@Usprite@@U?$less@V?$basic_string@DU?
$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBV?
$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?
$allocator@D@2@@std@@Usprite@@@std@@@2@@std@@A) already defined in Main.obj

1>fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

Here is my code structure:

SimpleTypes.h:

```
#pragma once

struct loc {

    int x;
    int y;
    int d;
    int s;

};

struct color {

    _int8 r;
    _int8 g;
    _int8 b;
    _int8 a;

};
```

ComplexTypes.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "SimpleTypes.h"
#include <string>

struct pixel {

    loc pos;

    color col;

};

struct sprite {

    std::string name;

    std::string file;

    loc pos;

};
```

ObjectHandler.cpp:

```
#include "ComplexTypes.h"
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

std::vector<pixel> pixels;
std::map<std::string, sprite> sprites;

void pixelsInit(){};

void spritesInit(){};

void pixelsUpdate(){};

void spritesUpdate(){};
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "ObjectHandler.cpp"

int main() {

    pixelsInit();
    spritesInit();

    while (true) {

        pixelsUpdate();
        spritesUpdate();

    };

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your project you are compiling `ObjectHandler.cpp` as an independent translation unit. And at the same time you also including `ObjectHandler.cpp` into `Main.cpp` where it gets compiled again as part of `Main.cpp`.

Thus, everything defined in `ObjectHandler.cpp` gets defined twice in your program. Hence the errors.

The question is: why are you including `ObjectHandler.cpp` into `Main.cpp`? What did you try to achieve by that?

And if you, for some unorthodox reason, really want/have to include `ObjectHandler.cpp` into `Main.cpp` and compile it as part of `Main.cpp`, then stop compiling `ObjectHandler.cpp` as an independent translation unit at the same time.

Meanwhile, a more traditional approach in this case would be to write a proper `ObjectHandler.h` file for your `ObjectHandler.cpp`. Something like

```
#pragma once
#include "ComplexTypes.h"
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

extern std::vector<pixel> pixels;
extern std::map<std::string, sprite> sprites;

void pixelsInit();
void spritesInit();
void pixelsUpdate();
void spritesUpdate();
```

and include it into `Main.cpp` instead.

Your `ObjectHandler.cpp` might look as follows

```
#include "ObjectHandler.h"

std::vector<pixel> pixels;
std::map<std::string, sprite> sprites;

void pixelsInit(){}
void spritesInit(){}
void pixelsUpdate(){}
void spritesUpdate(){}
```

Note the important detail: the `.h` file contains *declarations* only (functions have no bodies and objects are declared with `extern`), while `.cpp` file contains *definitions* (functions have bodies and objects are declared without `extern`)

Comment: That makes sense, what should I do instead? How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: @PlatinumFrog: It's really a matter of what you *want* to do. The "simplest" solution is: keep including `ObjectHandler.cpp` into `Main.cpp` but *remove* `ObjectHandler.cpp` from the list of Source files in your project, to make sure it does not get compiled independently.

Comment: However, including a `.cpp` file is a strange thing to do. A normal way to go about it would be: write an additional `ObjectHandler.h` file that only contains *declarations* (not definitions) of what you have in `ObjectHandler.cpp`. Include `ObjectHandler.h` into `Main.cpp` instead of  `ObjectHandler.cpp`. Keep `ObjectHandler.cpp` in the project as an independent source file.

Comment: It is up to you do figure out what you want to do. The question is, again: why did you `#include` `ObjectHandler.cpp` into `Main.cpp`? If this was random, then just stop doing this and follow the second approach: write a proper `ObjectHandler.h` and include it instead.

Comment: Main.cpp is supposed to handle the graphics rendering, and input. ObjectHandler.cpp is supposed to handle object logic and ai. They both need to take to each other.

Comment: I also low-key don't really know what I'm doing honestly. I have lots of experience with other languages, but only a little with this one. This project is a learning experience for me.

Comment: @PlatinumFrog: Well, in that case the bottom line is: you are not supposed to `#include` `.cpp` files into each other. `.h` files are for `#inclde`-ing, `.cpp` files are not. Don't `#include` `.cpp` files. If you want your `Main.cpp` to "talk" to `ObjectHandler.cpp` - write a proper header file `ObjectHandler.h` (see above)

Comment: (I added a sample `ObjectHandler.h` to the answer)